# Verlet algorithm implementation in Python

Tags: python, physics, numerical-methods, verlet-integration

I have problem with implementation of verlet algorithm in Python. I tried this code:

```
x[0] = 1
v[0] = 0
t[0] = 0
a[0] = 1
for i in range (0, 1000):
    x[i+1] = x[i] - v[i] * dt + (a[i] * (dt**2) * 0.5)
    v[i] = (x[i+1] - x[i-1]) * 0.5 * dt
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt
```

But it is not working properly. What is wrong?
I am looking for general code for Verlet algorithm.

Comment: Please tell us how it is not working properly. What output are you expecting? What output are you getting? Any errors? We need more info than "it doesn't work"

Comment: I left, some time ago, some implementation hints on the [verlet-integration] info-page.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear, but there are a few sources of error in your code.

Eg, for `i` > 0

```
x[i+1] = x[i]-v[i]*dt+(a[i]*(dt**2)*0.5)
```

tries to use the value of `v[i]`, but that element doesn't exist yet in the `v` list.

To give a concrete example, when `i` = 1, you need `v[1]`, but the only thing in the `v` list at that stage is `v[0]`; `v[1]` isn't computed until the following line.

That error should cause the Python interpreter to display an error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When asking for help on Stack Overflow *please* post the error messages with your question, preferably starting with the line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

That makes it a *lot* easier for people reading your question to debug your code.

FWIW, on the first iteration of your `for` loop, when `i` == 0, `x[i+1]` and `x[i-1]` both refer to the same element, since there are two elements in the `x` list at that stage, so `x[-1]` is `x[1]`.

Also, it's strange that you are storing your `t` values in a list. You don't need to do that. Just store `t` as a simple `float` value and increment it by `dt` each time through the loop; note that `t` itself isn't used in any of the calculations, but you may want to print it.

Your formulas don't appear to match those given on the Wikipedia page, either for the [Basic Störmer–Verlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Basic_St.C3.B6rmer.E2.80.93Verlet), or the [Velocity Verlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet). For example, in the code line I quoted earlier you are subtracting `v[i]*dt` but you should be adding it.

Perhaps you should consider implementing the related [Leapfrog integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) method. The synchronised version of Leapfrog is easy to code, and quite effective, IME.

From the Wikipedia link:

```
x[i+1] = x[i] + v[i] * dt + 0.5 * a[i] * dt * dt
v[i+1] = v[i] + 0.5 * (a[i] + a[i+1]) * dt
```

Generally, it's not necessary to actually store the `a` values in a list, since they will be calculated from the other parameters using the relevant force equation.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your implementation,

1. At step `0`, you are trying to access index `-1` which does not exist, and neither does the index `i+1` for the last index.
2. The acceleration is only defined at the first step and not for the other ones.
3. There is a sign error in the calculation of the next position.

Something like this should fix it,

```
import numpy as np
N = 1000
dt  = 0.1 
x = np.zeros(N)
v = np.zeros(N)
t = np.arange(0,(N+0.5)*dt, dt)
a = np.ones(N)*1.0  # initial condition
x[[0,1]] = 1
v[1] = v[0]+a[0]*dt

for i in range (1,N-1):
    x[i+1] = x[i]+v[i]*dt+(a[i]*(dt**2)*0.5)
    v[i+1] = v[i] + a[i]*dt
```

This won't be terribly efficient though, and it's better to use `scipy.integrate.ode` to solve the underlying differential equation of motion.